# Can't maximise Minecraft after toggling Fullscreen with F11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I accidently pressed F11 for PC minecraft and now the screen's all messed up.

When I turn Fullscreen OFF, it minimises, but the button to maximise is not working anymore.

How do I reverse it to normal?

Answer (score 3):

### Restart the game

Before exiting the game, set `Fullscreen` to `OFF`.

Upon starting Minecraft again, the option to maximize will be enabled.

If you don't want this to happen again, you can try disabling the F11 key temporarily [using an AutoHotkey script.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Override.htm) For more help on this, you may want to open a different question.