# How do I make the taskbar visible again when playing Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant see my task bar anymore and it makes going between windows hard, how do I exit Fullscreen? I have tried <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. When I change it to off in the video settings, it just makes a small window and i cant maximize it.

Comment: You may have to turn it off manually in the settings. Take a look at the answer posted here: [Turning fullscreen on made Minecraft crash, and now it crashes on start every time](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97289/turning-fullscreen-on-made-minecraft-crash-and-now-it-crashes-on-start-every-ti). Alternatively, turn it off (either F11 or through the settings), close Minecraft, and reopen it. See if that helps :)

Comment: Actually it seems this guy: [Can't maximise Minecraft after toggling Fullscreen with F11?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229320/28182) had the same problem as you, and the solution was to close Minecraft and reopen it after turning off Fullscreen, as I thought :)

Comment: How is this a dupe of a crashing question?

Comment: @aytimothy - dupe target should be my second link, I pasted the wrong one in :-/

Answer (score 0):

Robotnik is right, when you leave fullscreen with F11 close and re-open Minecraft, I had the same issue but reopening Minecraft let me maximize the screen again without going into fullscreen.